# In R & rmdformats, how can I control the width of kableExtra table?

Tags: css, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I'm hunting for a solution that would allow me to control the output of a `kableExtra` table in a `rmdformats` document.

Running example like that I get a table with a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom.

````
---
output:
  rmdformats::robobook:
    code_folding: show
    self_contained: true
    highlight: pygments
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
dt <- cbind(mtcars[1:5, 1:6],mtcars[1:5, 1:6])
```

```{r}
dt %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling()
```
````

[image]

This is not working well for largish tables and having so much wide space around I wanted to increase the table width.

I tried tinkering with `knitr` chunk options but this seems to only affect figures. Same goes for `rmdformats` options. Would some css be needed?

Answer (score 1):

Answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906002/increase-width-of-entire-html-rmarkdown-output) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367392/override-rmarkdown-theme-in-order-to-change-html-page-width/) point to css solution which works by adding this section right under YAML

```
<style type="text/css">
div.page-inner {
  max-width: 10000px !important;
}
</style>
```